# Can fat cells get into muscle cells?

Tags: human-biology

I heard a prof. saying that when people are getting older that there aren't only fat cells getting between and around muscle cells, so that humans gets weaker and weaker, but also that fat cells can get into muscle cells.

Is this true, and how is this done?

Comment: Fat in muscle cells or fat *cells* in muscle cells? The latter seems unlikely.

Comment: She talked about cells

Comment: I might double-check with your professor about what exactly she said. Fat accumulating in muscle cells is something that happens, but fat *cells* entering muscle cells seems pretty far-fetched.

Comment: I got her answer, and indeed she meant droplets of fat. So by this my question is answered